# Cirrus Logic Audio card replacement for recording

Tags: audio, hat

As is probably well known the Cirrus Logic Audio Card has stopped being manufactured and as such is proving very difficult to get. My reasons for wanting this card was that I needed something with a sample rate of 192khz for recording audio due to Nyquist's Sampling Theorem meaning I would be able to record at half this so 96khz.

Most of the replacements being talked about for this audio card focus on audio output. Those that do audio input, such as the Fe-Pi and the AudioInjector stereo sound card, usually only have a sample rate of 96 khz. The only sound card so far that suits my purpose is the PiSound however at $99 it is a significant step up in the price compared to the Cirrus Logic Audio Card.

Therefore my question is if anyone knows of an audio card for the Raspberry Pi 3 which has a 192khz sample rate?

Comment: Just got an email about this: https://www.seeedstudio.com/ReSpeaker-4-Mic-Array-for-Raspberry-Pi-p-2941.html not sure of the sample rate

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you are actually trying to do, you may not need an audio device. If you end up dumping the audio stream in a file and then run some calculation on it, you might as well use a data logger connected to a microphone. Commercial data loggers can easily reach 1MHz sampling rate and typically have more than two channels. Such devices also start at around $100 price tag, but they are much better acquisition tools than sound cards.

If you want so save money, it's possible to build a DIY data logger based on Arduino/Teensy/Pico, either programming it yourself or reusing someone else's project. 192kHz will most certainly not be possible on Arduino (which is an 8-bit 16MHz CPU), but will be on e.g. a Teensy or a Pico (which are both 32-bit 100+MHz CPUs).

Answer (score 1):

The best so far:

**The Element 14 [Wolfson Audio card](https://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-accessories/wolfson_pi)**:

> The Wolfson Audio Card, extends and enhances the Raspberry Pi® audio features beyond its native HDMI output with onboard HD Audio, at 24-bit, 192KHz. It offers Raspberry Pi® users similar flexibility to a PC soundcard to capture audio alongside their camera, and experiment with stereo digital capture and playback.
> Features:
>
> - Capable of rendering HD Audio, at 24-bit, 192kHz
> - 3.5mm 4-pole jack for a headset/boom mic combination for gaming or VoIP applications
> - Two DMIC microphones onboard for stereo recording
> - 3.5 mm jack Stereo Line Output for connection to devices such as external stereo amplifiers or powered speakers
> - 3.5mm jack for Stereo Line Input for high quality audio recording or capture

Comment: This is exactly what I need, the problem is though that it only works with the Raspberry pi Model A and B. As I have a Pi 3 I am looking for something that works with that(If it exists!)

Comment: Ah sorry, will keep my eyes peeled

Answer (score 1):

AudioInjector are about to launch an ultrasound card for the Pi :
[You can see it here on Kickstarter](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1250664710/1969608239?ref=3t7fyo&token=89ac6d37).

Its features are 192 kHz input and output audio, capable of recording through lines or 2 electret microphones. Possibility of SPDIF output.

Comment: This would be perfect, too bad they don't plan to ship it till January. I'll keep my eyes on it anyway, thanks.

Comment: What shipping date would swing you over ?

Comment: Mid-November to early December would be great :) I need a audio card like this for a science project you see, which is actually due in January.